# asp .net validation with jquery success callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I'm using asp .net mvc 4 and I have a html form using ajax validation.

I use this javascript code to know if the form is not valid. This code works.

```
$('#form').bind('invalid-form.validate', function () {
            alert("error");
            return false;
        });
```

But I cannot find a javascript callback for success ?

I tried :

```
$('#form').bind('valid-form.validate', function () {
            alert("success");

        });
```

or

```
 $('#form').validate({
                invalidHandler:
                function (form, validator) {
                    alert('error');
                },
                rules: function (form, validator) {
                    alert('success ');
                }
            });
```

But I never get the success alert. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you doing an Ajax form post, or regular?  Do you want the popup to appear before or after returning from the server?

Comment: actually I don't want to use the alert function now it's just for debugging, I want to hide a div by doing something like this $("myid").hide(). But I need to know if it's success or not

Answer (score 1):

use ajax.beginform

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete",new{id = Model.id}, new AjaxOptions 
  {
   OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
   OnFailure = "OnFailure",
   HttpMethod="Post"
 }))
```

then change OnSuccess/Onfailure to name of your java script function

Answer (score 0):

Bind to form.submit instead like this -

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).valid()) { // This checks if the form is valid
            alert("success"); // Or instead of success you can hide the form here
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                   // Goes in here after your MVC controller action is done
                },
                error: function (result) {
                   // Goes in here if your mvc controller action returns an error                   
                }
            });
        };
});
```